# elementary proof that every prime $p$ different from 2 is of the form 4$n$ + 1 or 4$n$ + 3

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I'd like to know if there is any flaw in this proof. I found it quite simplistic and it is unclear to me whether it exhausts or not the question.

Proposition: Every prime $p$ different from 2 is either of the form 4$n$ + 1 or 4$n$ + 3.

Proof:
If $p$ is prime and $p ≠ 2$, $p$ is an odd prime. Therefore $p$ can be written as: $p = 2k + 1$, for some $k$ $\in$ $\mathbf{N}$. It now suffices to show that making $k = 2n$ (for $n \in \mathbf{N}$) implies $p = 4n +1$ and making $k = 2n + 1$ implies $p = 4n + 3$.

Comment: It looks great, high five.

Comment: As long as you already know that every natural number is of the form $2n$ or $2n+1$, I'd say you're done.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.
Curiously, I hadn't noticed that the two values for $k$ I was using were the two forms possible for natural numbers, nice observation. I just found (algebraically) the values for $k$ that would make 2$k$ + 1 = 4$n$ + 1 (or 3).

Comment: It may be even easier to approach this via contrapositive or contradiction.  Suppose that $p$ is a prime different than $2$ and $p\neq 4n+1$ and $p\neq 4n+3$ for any $n$.  By quotient-remainder theorem this implies that $p=4n+2=2(2n+1)$ or $p=4n+0=2(2n)$, but in both cases it would be divisible by two.  Then $p$ is not actually a prime or is in fact $2$.

Comment: As suggested by others, your proof looks good. In a similar vein, every number can be written as $4k+i$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $i \in \{0, 1, 2, 3\}$. If $i = 0$, then the number is divisible by $4$; if $i = 2$, then $4k+2 = 2(2k+1)$ is divisible by $2$.

Comment: I've been for two days trying to prove this by contraposition and couldn't figure out how to make it work (guess due to lack of knowledge of the quotient-remainder theorem). Today I finally tried a direct prove and it followed smoothly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea, but your comment indicates that you may be unclear about the logic, so let's clarify that.

An integer $\,p\,$ is odd $\iff p = 2k+1\,$ for some integer $\,k.\,$ Now $\,k\,$ is either even $\,k = 2n\,$ (so $\,n = 4n+1)\,$ or odd $\,k = 2n+1\,$ (so $\, p = 4n+3).\,$ Thus an integer is odd $\iff$ it has form $\,4n+1\,$ or $\,4n+3.\,$ Note that the argument did not use primality, only oddness.

Or, by division $\, p = 4q+r\,$ for $\,0 \le r < 4.\,$ But $\,4q+r\,$ is odd $\iff r\,$ is odd $\iff r = 1,3$

Answer (score 1):

As a simple generalization,
note that,
for any integer
$m > 1$,
then all primes
$p > m$
must be of the form
$p=mn+k$
where
$n \ge 1,
0 \le k \le m-1$,
and
$(m, k) = 1$.

This problem is the case
$m = 4$,
for which the possible values of $k$
are $1$ and $3$.

Comment: That's true for *any* integer coprime to $\,m\,$ (and $> m),\,$ not only primes. Generally $\,(n,m)=1\iff (n\ {\rm mod}\ m,\,m) = 1.\ $